# jbpm 7.8 business-central not found

Tags: java, jbpm, business-process-management

After I started the wildfly with standalone command, I want to go to

> http://localhost:8080/business-central

and do some thing like

> http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.8.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#JBPMExamples

But **404 error** displayed. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

My build of wildfly does not work with that link. My kie workbench works with this link:
http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console

try that link after building with

```
standalone.bat -c my-standalone-full.xml
```

or

```
standalone.sh -c my-standalone-full.xml
```